# julia global variable definition in let block

Tags: julia, let

I had the following julia function

```
function fakeseq()
    let; global f(x)=unshift!(push!(x, 35) , 1);end; # not working
    #let; global f; f=x->unshift!(push!(x, 35) , 1);end; # works fine
    s1 = [rand(1:34) for i in 1:12]; 
    s2 = [rand(1:34) for i in 1:7]
    data = map(x->f(x), [s1, s2])
end
```

When I run that code I get the following error:

```
julia> fakeseq()
   ERROR: MethodError: no method matching f(::Array{Int64,1})
   The applicable method may be too new: running in world age 21823, while current world is 21824.
   Closest candidates are:        f(::Any) at REPL[1]:2 (method too new to be called from this world context.)
   Stacktrace:
   [1] _collect(::Array{Array{Int64,1},1}, 
   ::Base.Generator{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},##3#6}, ::Base.EltypeUnknown, 
   ::Base.HasShape) at ./array.jl:488
   [2] fakeseq() at ./REPL[1]:6
```

However, the second definition of f indicated with `# works fine` comment works. I couldn't get the exact difference between them, why that happens?

Comment: Have a look at the julia docs on [Redefining Methods](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/methods.html#Redefining-Methods-1). Also I expect you'll get different results depending on a) which order you run the above definitions (making sure you start in a fresh julia session.)

Comment: Also are you using julia v0.6? I wouldn't expect it to let you redefine `f` full stop...

Comment: @Alexander Morley I am using julia v0.6.2. When asking the question, I mean was I am using only one of the above let blocks in fresh julia session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AlexanderMorley pointed out, you need to look through

https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/methods.html#Redefining-Methods-1

or watch Jameson's Youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KGZ_9D_DbI

Generic functions are treated somewhat differently than anonymous functions in Julia. In the generic function case, what's going on is something like, the program compiles knowing what `f` in the global function table is, you modify `f`, but the calling function has already compiled to call what is no longer the correct function and thus it errors. The error is to stop [Issue #265](https://www.google.com/search?q=julia+265&oq=julia+265&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64l3.1165j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Anonymous functions are different though. In the anonymous function case, the calling function is setup to call whatever function is pointed to by that variable. In that case, it knows it's a global variable too so it's safe and doesn't inline it or anything like that, and so it's successful.